# Analysing categorical response variables

Tags: categorical-data, modeling

I have a dataset that i'd like to analyse, but I've only ever analysed data that has response variables as a measurement of something, but my response variable here is categorical - specifically, positive / negative.

The factors that influence the response variable are vessel type (three types) and temperature (four fixed temperature treatments). All samples have been manipulated to be positive, so ultimately what I am looking at, is which vessel is best for storing samples in at different temperatures.

Can someone suggest a suitable test that can give me some answers?

Comment: How do you measure how well a vessel stores samples?

Comment: You need to give some more details and context: Sample size, response is binary? But if so, look into logistic regression. That is the usual starting point for binary response!

Comment: Some more context: I have 3 types of vessel, each of which is storing a sample that when tested will give a positive / negative result. All samples are manipulated to be positive in order to see how long samples are viable in each container type before giving a false negative.

There are 5 fixed time points at which the samples in the vessels are tested - 0hrs, 8hrs, 24hrs, 36hrs, 48 hrs. There are 45 vessels of each type for each time point. E.g., there are 45 samples in 45 different vessel A's at 8 hours, all of which are known to be positive. Same for vessels B and C at each time point.